# Problema com FileDialog no QML

Tags: qt, dialog, qml

Estou tentando usar o componente `FileDialog` no QML

Eu fiz exatamente o mesmo código que está na documentação do Qt no link http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html e este código não mostrou o `FileDialog` e retornou o erro: `QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename`. Eu tentei escrever um código simples para testar, mas ocorreu o mesmo erro. Meu código está abaixo:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    visible: true

    width: 360
    height: 640

    maximumHeight: 640
    minimumHeight: 640

    maximumWidth: 360
    minimumWidth: 360

    title: "Acessar Galeria Test"

    Rectangle {
        id: principal

        anchors.fill: parent

        FileDialog {
            id: fileDialog

            title: "Please choose a file"

            folder: shortcuts.home

            visible: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `propriedade visible` do `FileDialog` não pode ser true enquanto o componente não estiver completo, por isto deve-se usar `Component.onComplete` para definir o `FileDialog` como `true`. Então o código deve ficar desta forma para funcionar:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    visible: true

    width: 360
    height: 640

    maximumHeight: 640
    minimumHeight: 640

    maximumWidth: 360
    minimumWidth: 360

    title: "Acessar Galeria Test"

    Rectangle {
        id: principal

        anchors.fill: parent

        FileDialog {
            id: fileDialog

            title: "Please choose a file"

            folder: shortcuts.home

            visible: false
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        fileDialog.visible = true;
    }
}
```